# Passing model instance's id in Django modelformset_factory

Tags: django

I am using `modelformset_factory` to be able to edit one parameter for all instances of a model. It works but I would like to display in the template the id of each individual model instance.
How can I do that ?

The view (the post request is handled by an other view):

```
def habits(request):
    HabitFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        Habit, extra=0, form=HabitModelForm)
    context = {
        'formset': HabitFormSet(
            queryset=Habit.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    }
    return render(request, 'habits.html', context)
```

the form:

```
class HabitModelForm(MyFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Habit
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]
```

the template:

```
<form action="{% url 'bulk_edit' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="table-responsive">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
      <table>
        <tbody>
        {% for form in formset %}
          <tr>
            <td>test {{form.instance_id}}</td> / This would be ideal but not working
          {% for field in form %}
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-right" value="Update">Update</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{form.instance.id}}` works perfectly fine...